# Behaviour of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I know that when I deny the browser getting the location, it will call the error callback.
However, it doesn't seem to be the case for FF4.

Can anyone enlighten me as to how to control what my js does if the user clicks dun share.

Thanks =D

Answer (score 1):

Is the user clicking "don't share for now" (which is equivalent to just not having made a decision yet, and hence doesn't make either the error or the success callback), or "never share" (which will give you an error callback last I checked)?

As for your JS...  just do whatever you would do if the user completely ignores the geolocation notification, which the user is completely free to do.

Comment: yup, the user is clicking dun share for now.

thing is in chrome it diverts to the error. alright then. thx =D